# Dialogflow analytics not Showing after hundreds of interactions for over a month

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an agent that has been receiving a few thousand queries for the last month.

The Analytics tab is however still showing blank: [Analytics dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1HPt.png)

Is there any setting I am missing? I have already enabled logging of interactions [Logging enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow6uJ.png)

Comment: Please contact support at https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: Thanks Max, I already did and shared my agent and history. Was advised it was escalated to the engineering team.